# Passing Var From JavaScript to php , error:

Tags: javascript, php

I'm triyng to pass a var value from javaScript to php and i'm getting this error
***Undefined index: postmarca in C:***  .
The objective was to avoid php returning the value of marcaID, which is the primary key and return the selection  name defined as "marca", which is obtained from a DB

What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php

$marca = $_POST['postmarca'];
 echo "$marca";
?>


<html>
<head>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="reg">
    <form>



<select name="marca" class="marca" id="marca">
    <option selected="selected">--Select MArca--</option>
        <?php
          $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabl_marca");
                     $stmt->execute();
                     while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                                     {
                            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['marcaID']; ?>">
      <?php echo $row['marcas']; ?></option>
    <?php
         } 
     ?>
                        </select>

        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="post();">
        </form>

</div>
</body>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
    function submit()
    {
    var marca= $('#marca').val();
        $.post('tester.php', {postmarca:marca}, function(data)
        {
            $('#reg').html(data);
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$_POST['postmarca']` will be set once data is posted from your script to the current script. When you run the script for the first time, `'postmarca'` has not been added to the global variable `$_POST` because the script has not posted the data assuming the current script is `tester.php`. Try adding a condition to check if the variable is available before using it i.e:

```
if(isset($_POST['postmarca'])){
    $marca = $_POST['postmarca'];
    echo $marca;
}
```

You might also want to change `onclick="post();"` to `onclick="submit();"`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the code as you said, and changed the the file tester.php to another caled submit.php, where i inserted that piece of code (isset .. ) i got rid of the error but it doesn't echo the value inserted. when i check the steps on console, i don't see the submit.php file beeing executed..... any aditional input ?  .

Comment: First I hope you included your javascript code in `tester.php` html and changed the js function `submit()` it to submit to submit to `submit.php`. `$.post('submit.php'...`

Comment: I passed the new code. Care to take a look? thank you

Comment: I had a look at it. When I changed the name of the js function `submit()` to another name e.g `getSubmission()`  it worked. That is the problem. I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

At the first load of the page, you try to get the POST value `postmarca`, but you did not submit any form.

You should had a condition to see if a form has been submitted, like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['postmarca'])) {
    echo $_POST['postmarca'];
}
```

I am assuming that the file you posted is called `tester.php`.

In that case, you may have an issue, because the `$.post` made in Javascript is an AJAX call, and it will include all your `tester.php` file, and you will have kind of a code inception here.

You can put the code I wrote in a new file, called per example `submit.php`, and then you avoid the code inception.

Comment: Thanks. I get you're point... but in that case,the result will be displayed in the submit.php , right ? how can i maintain the the results in the main file tester.php